# Why can't I bind my ObjectSet to my ASP.NET MVC list view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am developing mvc application related movie. 
I am trying to search the name of movie.

Its giving an error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[MvcMovie.Movie]', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcMovie.Models.Movie]'.

below is the searchIndex method code of Movie controller.

```
   public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
    {
        var movies = from m in db.Movies select m;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));

        }

        return View(db.Movies);
  }
```

And Below code of View page

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "SearchIndex";
```

}

Comment: Wow man, you 0% of accepted rate. This is bad, call my AH but I will not give the answer. Collaboration is the word ;)

Comment: FYI @devundef means that although you have asked quite a few questions, you haven't acknowledged right answers when you get them.  Some people are discouraged from helping you when they notice this.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.  Its nice to comment when you get a good answer, but people would really like it if you clicked the green "accept" check box.

Comment: Yes, because you don't even know if the author of the question had his problem solved or not, or even if he read the answers provided to him.   nilesh1foru, follow the link in @JimCounts comment to see why is important to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the results to an enumerable type.. such as a List:

```
return View(db.Movies.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the namespace of your `Movie` entity is `MvcMovie` not `MvcMovie.Models`

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet1[**MvcMovie.Movie**]
```

Change this

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
```

to this

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Movie>
```